# How to filter facebook share intent in android?

Tags: android

I have a share button. I share a message with some text and URL. It working well with whatsapp, Twitter and Gmail. But, in facebook share I'm able to share website link only. After, searching on web I have found ShareDialog class for facebook share.My question is how detect (ex: onClick() for facebook icon) when user click facebook icon on android default share dialog. Is it correct way ? or any other alternates is there?

My code :

```
public void shareApp() {       
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    String websiteLink = "https://www.manam.com";
    String playStoreLink = "http://www.google.com";
    String msg = "\nHey, found this cool & easy on-demand app.";
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, msg);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,playStoreLink + msg);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Facebook policy. 
When you implement sharing, your app should not pre-fill any content to be shared. This is inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, see [Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control).
I also don't see an option to detect click on facebook icon. And even if you can show your share dialog you wont be able to prefil any data